# How to design a Conversation view in windows 8 Metro App?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm Trying to design the Conversation View for a chat Application in windows 8 Metro App. I'm new to xaml designs, how to set the Conversation view like the image below,

[image: Conversation View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although at first time it seems this layout can be fit into Grid with three columns, I'm sure you would need scrolling at some point. So, you can just use `Canvas`, which allows free-floating controls. Place them with `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties.

Update: an illustration of what I mean:

```
<Canvas Width="300" Height="200">
    <Border Width="40" Height="40" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="60" Background="Red"/>
    <Border Width="160" Height="80" Canvas.Left="60" Canvas.Top="60" Background="LightGray"/>
    <Border Width="40" Height="40" Canvas.Left="250" Canvas.Top="150" Background="Red"/>
    <Border Width="160" Height="30" Canvas.Left="80" Canvas.Top="150" Background="LightGray"/>
</Canvas>
```

Let's pretend that red borders are user pics (put `Image` inside) and gray borders are messages (put `RichTextBlock` inside.) Canvas allows you to shift those blocks freely.